# git - changes are not reflecting pushing to main site

Tags: git

we are using multiple devolopment sites and once we do changes in devolopment site ,we will push the changes to main site.

[image]

My changes are not reflecting once i push the changes using below command :

```
git push staging development
```

**Edit**

my site is **site 1**, i pushed to **site 4** . changes i done is working fine in site 1 , but its not reflecting in site4. even the code i chnaged also is not moved to site4.

ex: if i change some code in form.html file, that code is not moving to site 4.
i added some normaal text, those also not copying to site4.

**Edit 2 - git config.file**

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "staging"]
    url = gituser@139.59.10.75:/var/www/sitename.repo
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/staging/*
[branch "development"]
    remote = staging
    merge = refs/heads/development
```

Comment: We need more information. What are `site 1` and `site 4`? What is it you're pushing to? Where do you want to see changes?

Comment: @NilsWerner please check edited question.

Comment: provide us your  git config file

Comment: where i can get `git config file @СеменихинМаксим

Comment: git config file .git/config

Comment: @СеменихинМаксим please check updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you pushed to the repository, you haven't updated the HEAD pointer. You'll need a checkout or reset on the remote to do that. It's kind of like you just did a fetch. You should look into setting up a [git hook for deployment](http://ryanflorence.com/deploying-websites-with-a-tiny-git-hook/) to automate this task.

Comment: we were not facing this problem before, today only this problem happend.

Answer (score 1):

So you pushed new commits to `staging`(remote) `development`(branch) and after this you  need to update the existing code itself to new changes. You probably need to look at [post-receive](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to achieve this.

> The post-receive hook runs after the entire process is completed and
>   can be used to update other services or notify users. It takes the
>   same stdin data as the pre-receive hook. Examples include emailing a
>   list, notifying a continuous integration server, or updating a
>   ticket-tracking system – you can even parse the commit messages to see
>   if any tickets need to be opened, modified, or closed. This script
>   can’t stop the push process, but the client doesn’t disconnect until
>   it has completed, so be careful if you try to do anything that may
>   take a long time.

and here is little example of post-receive hook

```
# --- Main loop

        oldrev=$(git rev-parse $1)
        newrev=$(git rev-parse $2)    
        refname="$3"

        while read oldrev newrev refname
        do

           branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
                if [ "development" = "$branch" ]; then
                echo 'branch:development';


                echo 'checkout site code';
                GIT_WORK_TREE=/Path/to/your/site/ git checkout -f

                fi
        done
```

or more simpler

```
# --- Main loop
    echo 'checkout site code';
    GIT_WORK_TREE=/Path/to/your/site/ git checkout -f
```

Comment: we were not facing this problem before, today only this problem happend.

Comment: this is common git behavior , so you are missing something